# GROUP BY count also missing types (Maria DB)

Tags: mysql

```
select kyc_type, count(*)
from kyc_table
where YEAR(created_at) = 2020
GROUP BY(kyc_type);
```

there are total 5 type of kyc

```
kyc = ['self','shg','mfg','jlg','or'];
```

if it find only one type of kyc like for example 'shg' then it return only

```
-- +----------+----------+
-- | kyc_type | count(*) |
-- +----------+----------+
-- | shg      | 2        |
-- +----------+----------+
```

this but I want others to return 0 if not exits how can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can perform a sub-select. First group by `kyc_type` and then for each type you perform a count.

```
select a.kyc_type,
       (
           select count(*)
           from kyc_table x
           where x.kyc_type = a.kyc_type and YEAR(created_at) = 2020
       ) as count
from kyc_table a
group by(kyc_type);
```

Comment: thanks it woks ( just one typo i found after x kyc_type it should be a.kyc_type) 
select a.kyc_type,
       (
           select count(*)
           from kyc_table x
           where x.kyc_type = a.kyc_type and YEAR(created_at) = 2020
       ) as count
from kyc_table a
group by(kyc_type);